# Split cell when table is too long for a page

Tags: python, reportlab

I have table in that one of the cells or most of the cells are too big for a page so I want to split the cell or do something that can generate pdf.

```
 colHedding1="Something"
 colHedding2="Something"
 colHedding3="Something"

 rowHedding={'k':'something','2':'something'}
 data=[]
 data.append([colHedding1,colHeading2,colHedding3])
 for k,r in dataobj.iteritems():

   count=1
   string=""
   for elt in r:
       string=string+'<font size=10 color="white" 
           name="Regular">'+str(count)+") 
           "+str(elt)+'</font>'+'<br />'
       count=count+1 

   data.append([str(k),rowHedding[str(k)],string])

style=[]
style.append(['GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.1,'#f5f5f5'])
style.append(['BACKGROUND', (0,0),(-1,0), '#fecd06'])
style.append(['VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'])

s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["Normal"]
s.alignment=TA_CENTER
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
s.fontSize = 10
data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in (data)]
t=Table(data2,1*[0.8*inch]+1*[2.5*inch]+1*[3.5*inch])
t.setStyle(TableStyle(style))

Story.append(t)
```

So when I generate pdf then it is showing table is too big for a page. I know the fact that one of the cells are too big for a page so how can I split a cell or something to generate pdf.